# Formatting whitespace in C++ output

Tags: c++

I have looked at several solutions to solve my issue but nothing seems to be working for me. I want my out put to align all the names, numbers chosen, and prize winnings on this code. Currently it outputs this:

```
3454 Atkins, Joe  7  6  5  4  3  2  1         7         $20.00    
4321 Barber, John      11  22  7  8  45  12  10         1         $0.00    
8976 Dollar, Kim      44  33  22  11  10  9  4         1         $0.00
```

I believe I would need the names to right align to fix this issue but nothing I have tried is working. Here is my code:

```cpp
 cout << student_info[i].id_num;
 cout << setw(10) << student_info[i].student_name << setw(10);

 for(int j = 0; j < LOTTERYNUMBERS; j++)
     cout << student_info[i].lotteryNumbers[j] << "  ";

 cout << setw(10) << student_info[i].lotteryMatches << setw(10) << setprecision(2)
      << fixed << showpoint << "$" << student_info[i].prizeMoney << endl;
```

Comment: Do you just need a `setw(4)` before printing the numbers?  Or thereabouts...  I think the `setw()` must come before the output operation (the value to be printed).

Comment: @VictorGubin I think that depends on the members of `decltype(*student_info)` and their types.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am somewhat against guessing without knowing what `decltype(*student_info)` is.

Comment: Also, since all the student names are longer than 10 characters, I'm not convinced `setw(10)` is helping much.

Comment: The formatting abilities of the standard stream library are rather poor. I would consider finding a library for this. Something like https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt perhaps?

Comment: @Galik It is sufficive for the task at hand.

Answer (score 6):

Since you failed to update your question with a definition of the type of `student_info` now for several hours, I'll assume that it is something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <array>

// that:
struct student_info_t {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    std::array<int, 7> numbers;
    int matches;
    long money;
};

int main()
{
    student_info_t student_info[] {
        { 3454, "Atkins, Joe",  {  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1 }, 7, 2000 },
        { 4321, "Barber, John", { 11, 22,  7,  8, 45, 12, 10 }, 1,    0 },
        { 8976, "Dollar, Kim",  { 44, 33, 22, 11, 10,  9,  4 }, 1,    0 }
    };

    for (auto const &s : student_info) {
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << s.id << ' ' << std::left << std::setw(15)
                  << s.name << std::right;
        for (auto const &n : s.numbers)
            std::cout << std::setw(4) << n;
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << s.matches << "  $" << std::setw(8) << std::fixed
                  << std::setprecision(2) << s.money / 100. << '\n';
    }
}
```

#### Sample Output:

```
3454 Atkins, Joe       7   6   5   4   3   2   1   7  $   20.00
4321 Barber, John     11  22   7   8  45  12  10   1  $    0.00
8976 Dollar, Kim      44  33  22  11  10   9   4   1  $    0.00
```

---

### Plan-B:

If you want the currency sign attached to the value you can use a stringstream:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <sstream>

struct student_info_t {
    int id;
    std::string name;
    std::array<int, 7> numbers;
    int matches;
    long money;
};

int main()
{
    student_info_t student_info[]{
        { 3454, "Atkins, Joe",  {  7,  6,  5,  4,  3,  2,  1 }, 7, 2000 },
        { 4321, "Barber, John", { 11, 22,  7,  8, 45, 12, 10 }, 1,    0 },
        { 8976, "Dollar, Kim",  { 44, 33, 22, 11, 10,  9,  4 }, 1,    0 }
    };

    for (auto const &s : student_info) {
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << s.id << ' ' << std::left << std::setw(15) 
                  << s.name << std::right;
        for (auto const &n : s.numbers)
            std::cout << std::setw(4) << n;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << '$' << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << s.money / 100.;
        std::cout << std::setw(4) << s.matches << std::setw(10) << ss.str() << '\n';
    }
}
```

#### Sample Output:

```
3454 Atkins, Joe       7   6   5   4   3   2   1   7    $20.00
4321 Barber, John     11  22   7   8  45  12  10   1     $0.00
8976 Dollar, Kim      44  33  22  11  10   9   4   1     $0.00
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you didn't provide enough code, I will not be able to replicate your code to get output. However, something you can do would be using tabs.

```
cout << student_info[i].id_num;
cout << setw(10) << student_info[i].student_name << setw(25);

for(int j = 0; j < LOTTERYNUMBERS; j++)
 cout << student_info[i].lotteryNumbers[j] << "  ";

 cout << setw(30) << student_info[i].lotteryMatches << setw(10) << setprecision(2)
  << fixed << showpoint << "$" << student_info[i].prizeMoney << endl;
```

Comment: You say "something you can do would be using tabs" but there are not tabs in your code. Even if there were, that would not match OPs requirements.

Comment: Forgive me but I am not sure how to format on Stackoverflow.